# Attempting to iterate HashMap with a for-loop yields null?

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

Here is the declaration of `Data.ListGroupedProducts`

```
public static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, WrapperProduct>> ListGroupedProducts = new HashMap<>();
```

My reason for doing this is to replace an object deep inside a collection with a new/updated object. I Continue to get `null` when attempting to `get` the collection I need within the HashMap.

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my debugging, mouse over `Data.ListGroupedProducts`.
[image]

The red arrow is what I'm attempting to reach... Is it not possible to iterate this with a for-loop?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to [Boann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/964243/boann)'s answer, I was able to fix the problem. Here is the full method in case anyone falls for the same mistake I made of attempting to use a for-loop for iterating over a KeySet!

```
    //Product coming in, has the latest updates and this will be used
    //to update the product deep in Data.ListGroupedProducts.
    public boolean UpdateListGroupProducts(ManifestProduct product) {

        for(int a=0; a < Data.SelectedInvoice.size(); a++){
            String invoiceNumber = Data.SelectedInvoice.get(a).ID;

            if(Data.ListGroupedProducts.containsKey(invoiceNumber)){
                //Iterate over each key using a keyset, we will then use the key on the for-loop
                //to retrieve the inner object and manipulate it as needed.
                for(String key: Data.ListGroupedProducts.get(invoiceNumber).keySet()){
                    for(int x=0; x < Data.ListGroupedProducts.get(invoiceNumber).get(key).ProductList.size(); x++){
                        String productID = Data.ListGroupedProducts.get(invoiceNumber).get(key).ProductList.get(x).ID;
                        String productItemID = Data.ListGroupedProducts.get(invoiceNumber).get(key).ProductList.get(x).ITEMID;

                        if(product.ID.equals(productID) && product.ITEMID.equals(productItemID)){
                            //Use ArrayList's set method to replace a position in the array with a new instance.
                            Data.ListGroupedProducts.get(invoiceNumber).get(key).ProductList.set(x, product);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }//Inner For
                }//Outer For
            }
        }
        return false;
   }
```

Comment: Can you please reduce this to a [MCVE]? Please follow Java naming conventions. If you're going to reuse the value of `Data.ListGroupedProducts.get(invoiceNumber)`, extract it to a shortname variable and reuse that. Makes for much more readable code.

Comment: `a <= Data.SelectedInvoice.size()-1` is usually written as `a < Data.SelectedInvoice.size()`.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. You call `containsKey` on `Data.SelectedInvoice.get(a).ID`, then you call `get` on `Data.SelectedInvoice.get(a).ID.toString()`. Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: @PaulBoddington New to Java--containsKey returns the value? Thought i was just checking and thats why I did `get` afterwards..

Comment: `containsKey` checks whether the key is in the map and returns `true` or `false`. It's the same thing you should pass to `get`. Have you tried adding `.toString()` to the thing you pass to `containsKey()`?

Comment: @AndyTurner `Size()` returns the actual count of the collection (1,2,3...) since i'm iterating with a `for-loop` i need to subtract one to start at zero, no? That was I can pass in the `for` counter to inner collections and retrieve values...

Comment: @Dayan `a <= b - 1` is identical to `a < b`, provided `a` and `b` are `int`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks Andy, good point lol

Comment: @PaulBoddington I first check if the invoice is found in the collection of keys, if it is then i retrieve the value corresponding to that key and save the invoice in a string variable in order to reuse it while accessing deeper in the HashMap.

Comment: @Dayan I'm lost I'm afraid. You need to show a full example including the types of all the variables.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I'm sorry, I will clean this up a bit to make it easier to follow. Give me a min

Comment: @PaulBoddington I updated it best i could.

Comment: Why is my question downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)` style of loop to iterate a `HashMap`. The key-value pairs in the map don't have an associated numeric index, or a particular order. So calling `get(x)` on the map attempts to look up the value for key `0`. But there is no such mapping, because that map's key type is `String`, and the real key is `"FREEZER"`. Since there is no mapping with key `0`, `get` returns `null`.

To iterate the `WrapperProduct` instances that are the values of the inner `HashMap`, replace the `for(int x...)` loop with:

```
for (WrapperProduct w : Data.ListGroupedProducts.get(invoiceNumber).values()) {
    System.out.println(w);
}
```

[This page](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-iterate-over-a-map-in-java/) explains more about ways of iterating maps.

Comment: I realized my problem, I was aware i could use `foreach` just fine but didn't because I thought i was not going to be able to replace the inner `obj` found in the inner HashMap with a new version of that `obj`. I was wrong, thanks for the page you linked and explanation.

Comment: You can mutate the properties of an object in the map just fine, if it's not immutable. If you want to replace it with an actually different object instance then you will need to iterate the map by key-value pair, or by key, so that within the loop you have access to the key to use in the map `put` call.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try with key-value pair and see how that works out if the implementation i have at the moment doesn't work.